# iOS App Store gives me "Cannot connect to the iTunes store” error message

Tags: ios

After updating to iOS 6 certain tabs in my app store give me an "Cannot connect to the iTunes store” error message and the genuis tab is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Various sites have figured out how to fix this error message:

> 1. Go to Settings in your iPhone.
> 2. Click on General.
> 3. Go to Date and Time.
> 4. Change Set Automatically to Off.
> 5. Go to Set Date & Time.
> 6. Click on Today’s Date.
> 7. Move the year one year forward one year.
> 8. Launch app store, should have no errors
> 9. Go back to Settings, General, Date and Time, and change Set Automatically to on